# Needing to join on a replace statement

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am needing to get usernames for a report on my database. I do not have a table with just user names but I do have a table with email address which is the same thing just @blahblah.blah after the user name. what I've done for this is:

```
replace(email.email_address, '@blahblah.blah', '') as user_name,
```

this works fine with the rest of my code until I need to join on this. Now I have a to join a another table using the user name as a key. I'm trying to figure out how I can use a left join and join on that data that is edited in the replace statement.

Comment: I think a `LEFT` or `substring` function would work better.

Comment: nothing but `left join on people.username = replace(email.email_address, '@blahblah.blah', '')`

Comment: You say you don't have a table containing usernames .. but then you say you need to join to another table using the username.  A puzzling contradiction.

Comment: I should have stated that the username that I'm needing to join is an imported csv file that only has two columns. One with user names and the other has a date and time stamp that I'm needing. I can't use the user names from the imported file because there is not a key that I can join on. So in all, i'm needing to create the username by removing the @blahblah.blah from the email address and then join the imported table on that user name so that I can have the date and time stamp data from the other column in the imported table.

Answer (score 0):

The username is the substring up to `'@'`, so do it like this:

```
..left join othertable
on othertable.username = substr(email.email_address, 1, instr(email.email_address, '@') - 1)
```